# Submit a question for locking

Tags: support, moderation

[This question about a certain font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82370/font-from-old-70s-american-engineering-schematics) gets a lot of views (5K at the moment), and answers, although it is *essentially* unaswerable - because the original font is not a digital font. Which leads to people submitting suggestions, which in turn evokes comments such as "that does not look anything like it", and so on.

I feel the 8 current answers are enough to show there is a variety of interpretations, and, similar to other resource gathering questions, it may best be locked.

Locking a question is an option left to moderators; suggesting to do so does not appear in the regular list of Close Votes, nor in the list of Flags. There is a custom option "this question needs your attention", but I don't feel confident enough to tick that because of the term ***needs***: I'd rather merely *suggest* looking at this question and its long term usefulness.

Apart from this very action (putting it forward as an example on Meta), is there a regular way to submit questions for locking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Flag then press "In Need of Moderator Intervention" and state your case. Can also ping myself, Vincent, DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ, JohnB, CAI, or Joojaa in Chat to ask. Members with 15,000 rep have the ability to "Protect Question."

If you feel the question is actually off-topic then despite how many views and answers it gets you can Vote to Close it.

---

Regarding that specific question, it's received zero flags on the question, answers, or comments. There's been no spam answers or arguments on it. I see no reason at this time to Protect it.

Comment: That's fair. I realize the sheer amount of views can be a positive thing as well, as far as GD-SE goes. I'll save the Moderator flags for serious problems, then.